# Magento 2 default currency based on country

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.7

in my website i have 2 currency & user can. One is USD and other is Riyal. Default currency is USD . There is drop down in near to our logo in which customer can change the currency to Riyal and USD. Default option is USD

What i want is, any customer taking our website from Saudi Arabia we have to show them riyal currency for all other country we have to show them USD Curreny .

How can i do this ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this work, you need to check your ip from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and find the country code from MaxMind’s GeoIP2 database(https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).

Reference: https://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-basic-exercise-5.php

After that, you need to use event observer controller_action_predispatch in your module in app/code/your_vendor/your_module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
            <observer name="currency_init_for_country" instance="your_vendor\your_module\Observer\PreDispatchObserver" shared="false" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

In the your_vendor\your_module\Observer\PreDispatchObserver.php file you need to add:

```
<?php

namespace your_vendor\your_module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class PreDispatchObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // logic for taking current country from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and checking from maxmind database and find the country code.then you can add a if else condition for currecny here based on country code.
        $currency = 'USD';

        if ($this->getStoreCurrency() !== $currency) {
            $this->storeManager->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($currency);
        }
    }

    private function getStoreCurrency()
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of creating new module can i write it in any other file ? please check . i don't want to install any new module.

Comment: New module is not mandatory. I guess, you will have some existing module. You can just add the event observer in any existing modules in etc/frontend/events.xml file. Also, if your website is redirected to specific website based on the country then you don't need the ip based database search as well. Just need to check the current website code using $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode() and setting the currency accordingly.

Comment: now i had another doubt. i created new question for that . Could youplease check